# Cannot get correct json response using GoLang get

Tags: json, go

I'm new to Go and trying to write a simple web crawler. I'm using duck duck go's api and trying to display search results.

https://duckduckgo.com/api

This is my code -
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)


func main() {
    getDuckDuckGo("food")
}

func getDuckDuckGo(keyword string) <- chan string{
    resp, _ := http.Get("http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + keyword + "&format=json&pretty=1")
    c := make(chan string)


    fmt.Println(resp)
    var respMap map[string]interface{}
    fmt.Println(respMap)


    fmt.Println(respMap)
    return c
}
```

My resp println gives me this -

```
&{200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Connection:[keep-alive] Content-Type:[application/x-javascript] Date:[Sat, 20 Dec 2014 00:41:49 GMT] Cache-Control:[max-age=1] Expires:[Sat, 20 Dec 2014 00:41:50 GMT] Server:[nginx] X-Duckduckgo-Locale:[en_US]] 0xf840053c20 -1 [chunked] false map[] 0xf84007c000}
```

Rather than any json.

Am I doing the GET request correctly?

Comment: Don't ignore your errors!

Comment: I edited it to get past the go errors - but I still get the same response...so I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: You example still doesn't do anything with the http response, and prints an empty `respMap` twice.

Answer (score 1):

At least, you should do below things:

1. Check error of `http.Get()`
2. Get `io.Reader` by `resp.Body` for HTTP body data
3. Use `json.Decoder` to decode json

Your `getDuckDuckGo()` should be became like this:

```
func getDuckDuckGoImproved(k string) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://api.duckduckgo.com/?=" + k + "&format=json")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    r := make(map[string]interface{})
    d := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    if err := d.Decode(&r); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return r, nil
}
```